# Sending and Receive data from a web page - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following situation:

I am using the [selenium python binding](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org) for send to a web page one word, this web site perform some processing (divide the word in the silabes that contain it) and show to the user the result in the following picture of this way:

Word: Competition

Result: Word "Competition" divide in silabes

[image]

In the inspect element tool, I've been checking the id's attributes for the input text

[image]

From the following python script through selenium Web driver API, I am sending some word to the search input text and press ENTER Key too for perform the action.

```
# Currently supported WebDriver implementations are Firefox, Chrome, Ie and Remote
from selenium import webdriver

# Interacting with the RETURN KEY
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Creating a web driver firefox instance
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# With the get method we go to the webpage in the url given
driver.get("http://tip.iatext.ulpgc.es/silabas/Default.aspx")

# Assertion that checks if the word "Silabeador" is in the title webpage
assert "Silabeador" in driver.title

# WebDriver let me interact with items in a web page through of their attributtes
# More information http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_TextBox1")
elem.send_keys("Competencia")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Four different types of call the same content position
print (driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_Table1"))
print (driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table"))
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/table[1]'))
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='Form1']//table[@id='MainContent_Table1']"))

# Call the form that contain all output information 
print (driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form[1]"))

#print (driver.page_source)

assert "No results found" not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

And my output, when I execute the script is the following:

1. Open the firefox browser and put the word sent and execute the "enter" form action

[image]

And my output in the print instructions is the following:

```
/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python /home/bgarcial/workspace/Test/example/search.py
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1ace67-0fb3-42b6-9cc9-af9c58b1715e", element="{320d5570-1060-4d4a-a5e6-af557f28f228}")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1ace67-0fb3-42b6-9cc9-af9c58b1715e", element="{320d5570-1060-4d4a-a5e6-af557f28f228}")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1ace67-0fb3-42b6-9cc9-af9c58b1715e", element="{320d5570-1060-4d4a-a5e6-af557f28f228}")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1ace67-0fb3-42b6-9cc9-af9c58b1715e", element="{320d5570-1060-4d4a-a5e6-af557f28f228}")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="7f1ace67-0fb3-42b6-9cc9-af9c58b1715e", element="{d16859b4-2029-4ba9-8eeb-d3c8371053eb}")>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

In the element attribute is returning the object representation or memory address (? - Is this right? -) of the elements form that I am asking ...

How to can I retrieve the content or information, in this case the word "Competition" processed, for this situation divided in silabes (Com-pe-ti-tion)and not the string or representations that I currently receive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see printed are the [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) instance string representations.

You need to locate the second row in the table and get the second cell. You can do it in one go:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table#MainContent_Table1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)").text
```

Note that, once we've located the element, we are getting the `.text` to retrieve the element text.

---

You may encounter timing issues - the element might not be present when you look for it. If this is a case, [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) is to the rescue:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#MainContent_Table1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)"))
)
print(element.text)
```

---

Demo:

```
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

In [3]: 
In [3]: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

In [4]: driver.get("http://tip.iatext.ulpgc.es/silabas/Default.aspx")

In [5]: elem = driver.find_element_by_id("MainContent_TextBox1")

In [6]: elem.send_keys("Competencia")

In [7]: elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

In [8]: print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table#MainContent_Table1 > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)").text)
Com-pe-ten-cia
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed explanation in this sample. I don't knew the nth-of-type selector for find matches between parents and child tags or elements.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested the code below but it will be something along those lines. You could also use re instead.

```
def syllables(word):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    starts = ['ou','ei','ae','ea','eu','oi']
    endings = ['es','ed','e']
    word = word.lower().strip(".:;?!")
    word.split(vowels)
    word.split(starts)
    words.split(endings)
    return word
```

Comment: I think the question is selenium-specific and about extracting information from a specific web-site.